# Landscape_install_error

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, landscape

While trying to install the Landscape(17.03) on to my VM (Ubuntu 18.04 server), I am getting the below error and I tried the option given on ubuntu sties.

[image: imgur image]

```
venu@landscape01:~$ sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
Error : unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please copy and paste that text into your question ( edit and add it)!

Comment: Again what version of Ubuntu are talking here, as the error says that package doesn't exist for your Ubuntu version so might be available in a private repo or not!

Answer (score 0):

Landscape server is not available for 18.04 yet. Supported version is 16.04 https://help.landscape.canonical.com/

Client for desktop/server is available for 18.04